# Why JSTL has sql related tags

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Considering JSP should only be a view and shouldn't be making any calls to the database, then why do we have JSTL sql library? Isn't the availability of such tags tempt us in making database calls from JSP. I am sure it is there for some purpose but don't know what it is. I would like to get some opinions on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right. There shouldn't be a sql library. The first thing the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html) says about it is:

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 14-8 are designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in JavaBeans components.

which is a diplomatic way of saying: don't use this. If you're using it, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: sorry, a same minute (same) answer, deleting mine

Comment: @MasterSlave no need to be sorry. That is unavoidable and it happens all the time :-)

Comment: Yes, that was my guess as well that it is only for quick prototyping not for production applications.

Answer (score 0):

Every JSP needs to show the data and data source could be from say webservice, sql etc. So although it should be model who should fetch the data but still there are cases where you can't ignore sql call from JSP (say for e.g. if you are moving from legacy scriptlet to pure jstl) in that case you could use sql jstl library.